# Delay rendering of a components template in Ember for specified time?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component, but I want to add an option that will delay the rendering of the template for a specified time, i.e:

```
{{pre-loader radius=60 delay=2000 message="Page is loading data"}}
```

And the components template:

```
<svg class="spinner" width="{{size}}px" height="{{size}}px" viewBox="0 0 {{viewBoxSize}} {{viewBoxSize}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="{{strokeWidth}}" stroke-linecap="round" cx="{{halfViewBoxSize}}" cy="{{halfViewBoxSize}}" r="{{radius}}"></circle>
</svg>
{{#if (is-greater-than message.length 0)}}
  <div class='loading-message'>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

I have one working solution that I will post as an answer below but I'd welcome a better approach than having to use an `{{if}}` in the template itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is two fold:

1) Add an if around the entire template:

```
{{#if delayComplete}}
  ...
{{/if}}
```

2) Add the following code to the javascript of my component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.set('_wasDelayed', false);
  },
  delayComplete: Ember.computed({
    set(key, val) {
      return val;
    },
    get() {
      var delay = this.get('delay');
      var wasDelayed = this.get('_wasDelayed');

      if (delay && !wasDelayed) {
        this.set('_wasDelayed', true);

        this.startDelayPolling(delay);

        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }),
  startDelayPolling: function(delay) {
    this._poller = Ember.run.later(this, () => {
      this.set('delayComplete', true);
    }, delay);
  },
  stopDelayPolling: function() {
    Ember.run.cancel(this._poller);
  },
  willDestroy: function() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.stopDelayPolling();
  },
  ...
});
```

i.e. delayComplete is a computed that sets a timer to update itself if a delay is specified. Also add willDestroy to handle situation where timer is still running but component gets destroyed.